# schedulable class shows 0% coverage while trying to deploy to Production

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests, schedulebatch

I have a Schedulable class which calls a Batch class, I have enough coverage when checking in sandbox, But when trying to deploy to production Scheduler class shows 0% and Batch class shows 60%. I am scheduling the class using Schedule Apex in SETUP not with CRON Expression .Can someone help me with this? Below is the Scheduler class and Batch class. TIA.

**Scheduler class**

```
global class BatchScheduler implements Schedulable{  
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){  
        BatchCounter batch = new BatchCounter ();           
            database.executebatch(batch);       
    }
}
```

**Test scheduler**

```
@istest  
private class BatchSchedulerTest{ 
 @istest 
    static void testschedule() {  
        Test.StartTest();  
        BatchScheduler testsche = new BatchScheduler ();  
        String sch = '0 0 23 * * ?';  
        system.schedule('Test status Check', sch, testsche );  
        Test.stopTest();  
    }
}
```

**Batch class**

```
global class BatchCounter implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{  
static final String businessHoursId;  
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){  
String query = 'SELECT Id, numberField__c,statusField__c,Submitteddate__c FROM objectName__c WHERE Submitteddate__c !=null '+' AND statusField__c IN (\'Assigned\', \'Submitted\', \'InProgress\')';  
 return Database.getQueryLocator(query);  
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<TMA__c> tmas){  
for (TMA__c tma : tmas){  
if (isBusinessHours(businessHoursId)){  
tma.numberField__c+=1;  
}
}  
update tmas;  
}  
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)  
{ }  
private static Boolean isBusinessHours(Id businessHoursId){  
BusinessHours businessHours = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE Id = :businessHoursId];  
if (businessHours != null){  
Datetime currentDatetime = Datetime.now();  
return BusinessHours.isWithin(businessHoursId, currentDatetime);  
}  
return false;  
} }
```

**Test Batch so far**

```
@isTest  
private class BatchUpdatTest{  
@isTest static void testExecute() {  
        // Create test records
        List<TMA__c> tmacList = new List<TMA__c>();  
        for(Integer i=0;i<5;i++){  
            tmacList.add(new TMA__c(  
                Name = 'Test TM Action ' + i,  
                Submitteddate__c= System.today(),  
                Status__c = 'Assigned'  
            ));  
        }  
        insert tmacList;                
        BatchCounter batch = new BatchCounter();  
        Test.startTest();          
        // Execute batch  
        Database.executeBatch(batch);  
        Test.stopTest();                    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you include your test classes in the deployment?  Please [edit] your post to include your test classes.

Comment: @DavidCheng Yes, I did. I have included the test classes Please check and revert.

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your code.

Comment: Do note that the `testmethod` keyword is deprecated (i.e. you should not use it any more). Use the `@isTest` annotation for the individual test methods instead (and the test class itself still needs the `@isTest` annotation as well).

Comment: @DerekF That was my mistake, I updated the actual code now. In higher and lower testing environment i have 100% coverage. Issue is when the devops team tries to validate the package for PROD deployment, It shows 0% coverage.Helpp!